# Repeat action with Cron

Tags: php, file, cron, timer-jobs

I'm using my cpanel to lunch a cron action thats open a file a write Hello every minute.

But that task is not working.

This is my code :

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
$handle = fopen("passes.txt", "a");
fwrite($handle, "Hello");  
fwrite($handle, "\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

When I try to lunch the script directly in my browser it's working fine, but the cron job isn't working at all.

I've used this command to launch the script :

```
* * * * * * http://www.mysite.com/myfile/write.php
```

.

```
EDIT:
```

All your `commands` are not working for me.

I'm using `Cron tasks` in my `cpanel`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in 2 ways

if you have wget on your system:

1: `* * * * * * wget -O /dev/null http://www.mysite.com/myfile/write.php`

else:

2:     `* * * * * * /path/to/your/php/bin/php /path/to/myfile/write.php`

Answer (score 2):

to run this cron every minute you have to use something like this:
*/1 * * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/myfile/write.php
or
* * * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/myfile/write.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the request via wget, to simulate a browser request:

```
* * * * * * wget -q http://www.mysite.com/myfile/write.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not a command you could run in a shell. It should either be

```
php /var/www/yoursitePath/yourFile/write.php
```

or

```
curl http://www.mysite.com/myfile/write.php
```

I don't know what the `header` should do for you in a script though, can't see that having any effect whatsoever when called like this